# How to remove text from a specific line in file without creating unwanted space using c#?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to remove text from a specific line in the file that i have created "Test.txt".

Here is the text written in Test.txt:
1
2
3
4
5

1
2
3
4
5

1
2
3
4
5

Now what i want to happen is when i'm going to remove 2 - 4 in the 2nd iteration, the output should be like this:
1
2
3
4
5

1
5

1
2
3
4
5

What i want is to remove only spaces that the corresponding text was removed from and preferably without involving other spaces.
But when i tried the code it gave me this output:
1
2
3
4
5

1



5

1
2
3
4
5

As you can see the above output, that is the unwanted space that i'm talking about. Below is the code that I have tried:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace TestCode
 {
   class Program2
  {
    static void Main()
    {
        lineChanger("", @"C:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\MusicStore\Pages\Test.txt", 8);
        lineChanger("", @"C:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\MusicStore\Pages\Test.txt", 9);
        lineChanger("", @"C:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\MusicStore\Pages\Test.txt", 10);

    }

    static void lineChanger(string newText, string fileName, int line_to_edit)
    {
        string[] arrLine = File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
        arrLine[line_to_edit - 1] = newText;
        File.WriteAllLines(fileName, arrLine);
    }
}
}
```

Also please feel free to suggest any proper techniques and kindly include actual examples.

Comment: The problem is that you are not removing a line. You are changing the contents of a line with an empty space.

Comment: Try something like this `File.WriteAllLines("", arrLine.Where(s => s != ""));`

Comment: @Steve hit the nail on the head (except the wording is a little misleading: the line is not exchanged against an "empty space" -- there is not even a space! --, but against an empty line. *Removing* a line is a distinct operation from *deleting all contents from a line* but keeping the line. If you need to do both (the name of your function, `lineChanger`,  seems to suggest that you sometimes really want to change, not eliminate, a line), you need to define two distinct operations. For example you could have an enum defining the operation: DELETE, CHANGE, ADD (future enhancement!) etc.

Comment: i wonder why this has 2 negative votes. This problem was already solved perfectly and its still working great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see is this ok?

```
        int removeAt = 7; //or any thing you want
        int linesToRemove = 3; //or any thing you want
        string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Test.txt");
        List<string> arr = s.Split("\n".ToCharArray()).ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < linesToRemove; i++)
            arr.RemoveAt(removeAt);
        string result = "";
        foreach (string str in arr)
        {
            result += str;
        }
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("Test.txt", result);
```

I'm happy that you say it works for you, and here i add another solution, maybe in some cases you need to use this:

```
        int removeAt = 7; //or any thing you want
        int linesToRemove = 3; //or any thing you want
        string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Test.txt");
        List<string> arr = s.Split(new char[] { '\n' }).ToList();
        List<int> realBareRows = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(arr[i].Replace("\r", "")))
                realBareRows.Add(i);
        }
        List<string> newArr = s.Split(System.Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
        foreach (int j in realBareRows)
            newArr.Insert(j, "\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < linesToRemove; i++)
            newArr.RemoveAt(removeAt);

        string result = "";
        foreach (string str in newArr)
        {
            result += str + System.Environment.NewLine;
        }
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("Test.txt", result);
```

Comment: I've also tried your code but it gave me an exception. An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: Does your testing text have more than 5 lines?

Comment: its working now. i forgot that my Test.txt is empty at the moment. But I will still try this solution on my project.

Comment: I think the problem with this solution is it removes all the whitespace and it removes only the starting line, up until the loop ends. When i tried changing the index for the RemoveAt so that i can remove some text right in the middle, it is giving me an out of bounds error. Meaning, I can only remove the starting line and cannot remove something in the middle.

Comment: But you asked about removing the starting lines. Now what you exactly want? Please say me to update my answer.

Comment: I have changed the desired output above. Kindly check it out and see for possible solutions.

Comment: It is working but why is it creating newlines in between numbers? how do you remove those newlines? I want it to be intact as before just like the output that i have shown above.

Comment: But i tested this and i did not see this problem ...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134981/discussion-between-farzin-kanzi-and-brunoearth).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you remove the lines via `File.ReadLines`. You can do it like this:

```
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(fileName))
{

   //Add it to your arrLine and don't insert a line based on your condition. 
}
```

I'm not quite sure what's your condition here. I think it's based on the `line_to_edit`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can omit all the lines with 0 lenght

```
File.WriteAllLines(fileName, arrLine.Where(x => x.Length>0));
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but the output became 2 4 6 8 10.

Comment: I guess your are doing something wrong: the point is that you asked to omit the blank lines from the output of the files and that's exactly what the above line does...

Comment: I have changed the desired output above. Kindly check it out and see for possible solutions.

Comment: Maybe you want to replace `lineChanger("deleteMe",`... and then `x => !x.Equals("deleteMe")` in my solution! Anyway you should accept or mark useful the post when they meet the stated requirements without continuosly change the specs ;-)